# In C# winforms - How do you search database by date time picker?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been stuck on this for two days.  I simply want to search my table by date.  I am displaying in dataGridView.  If I select button dataGridView shows all data in table.  If I select date then press button I get the following message from the catch messagebox:

```
Conversion failed when converting data and/or time from character string.
```

Table name: FlightDetails
Column : DateDepart (date)

```
    string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myDB = new SqlConnection(ConString);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM FlightDetails WHERE DateDepart ='" + datDepartDate + "%'", myDB);

    try
    {
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sda.SelectCommand = com;
    DataTable dsDB = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dsDB);
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

    bs.DataSource = dsDB;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    sda.Update(dsDB);
    dataGridView1.Visible = true;

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013, C# winforms.  Guidance with code would be preferred please.  I am sure all I need to do is convert date time picker but I have tried with no success.

Comment: What is the type of `DateDepart` column? What is `datDepartDate` exactly?

Comment: print your sqlcommand to your screen before running to the database, then run the sqlCommand on the server to see wether this is a problem, anyhow probably a good'ol fashioned data mashup :)

Comment: Ah... SQL Injection 101 right there folks!

Comment: DateDepart = date...... datDepartDate is the datetimepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you add a `%` to the end, but you would be better off using parameters instead of strings,  especially for date values, since the string representation is culture-dependent:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM FlightDetails WHERE DateDepart = @datDepartDate", myDB);
com.Parameters.Add("@datDepartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
              .Value = datDepartDate;
```

Comment: I would also point out the [sql injection hazard](https://xkcd.com/327/) as well as the requirement that datDepartDate should be an instance of the DateTime structure. Still got my upvote.

Comment: @ZoharPeled True in general, although assuming the source variable is a date value it didn't seem like a risk in this case.

Comment: I agree, but why not use this case to eliminate potential problems in other cases? If you explain the reasons to use parameterized queries, chances are the OP will start using them instead of concatenated ones.

Comment: Thank you for all your input.....getting closer but now the catch is saying "Failed to convert parameter value from a DateTimePicker to a DateTime"

Comment: If `datDepartDate` is a `DateTimePicker` control then you should be using `datDepartDate.Value`.

Comment: I can not thank you enough.  This has worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Some advice:  Learn to use the debugger, add watches, inspect variables, and research the documentation on classes and controls.  The problem would have been much more obvious by simply looking at the value that was used.